# PostgreSQL - time series interpolation

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "performances" with columns "date" and "count".
However, the rows are sparse i.e. there are many days for which there is no row, which implicitly means that the count = 0.
Is there a query I can do that when run on this:

```
date       count
2016-7-15  3
2016-7-12  1
2016-7-11  2
```

Would give me this:

```
date       count
2016-7-15  3
2016-7-14  0
2016-7-13  0
2016-7-12  1
2016-7-11  2
```

?

Comment: Check out the docs - specifically `generate_series()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` and a `left join`:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select s.dte, coalesce(q.count, 0) as count
from (select generate_series(min(q.date), max(q.date), interval '1 day') as dte
      from q
     ) s left join
     q
     on s.dte = q.date;
```